# Using compose navigation to pass optional arguments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following screen. The `id` is optional and the `menuActionType` is not optional

```
 object TaskDetailScreen : Screen(route = "task_detail_screen/{id}/{menuActionType}") {
        const val TASK_DETAIL_SCREEN = "task_detail_screen"
        const val TASK_ID = "id"
        const val MENU_ACTION_TYPE = "menuActionType"
    }
```

This is my composable and I have added the optional `id` to this route as an optional argument

```
composable(
    route = "task_detail_screen?id={id}",
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument(Screen.TaskDetailScreen.TASK_ID) {
                type = NavType.StringType
                nullable = true
                defaultValue = null
            }, navArgument(Screen.TaskDetailScreen.MENU_ACTION_TYPE) {
                type = NavType.StringType
                defaultValue = AgendaMenuActionType.OPEN.name
            }),
        deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink {
            uriPattern = AgendaDeepLinks.TASK_DEEPLINK
        })
    )
```

The navigation

```
navHostController.navigate(route = "task_detail_screen/${AgendaMenuActionType.OPEN.name}")
```

This is the action types

```
enum class AgendaMenuActionType(@StringRes val titleId: Int) {
    OPEN(R.string.open),
    EDIT(R.string.edit),
    DELETE(R.string.delete)
}
```

This is the error I get

```
Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/task_detail_screen/OPEN } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0xd809c992) route=agenda_screen}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error is because of two things: **Defining the route** with optional parameters and **Navigating with the right parameters**, here is how to solve it:

- First, you should redefine the route like the following:

```kotlin
route = "task_detail_screen?id={id}&menuActionType={menuActionType}",
```

- Second, when navigating, you can use the named parameter to pass only the needed parameters:

```kotlin
navHostController.navigate(route = "task_detail_screen?menuActionType=${AgendaMenuActionType.OPEN.name}")
```

Comment: thanks that worked like a charm. I have often watched your youtube videos, very informative.